# How to shrink LVM physical volume with free space

Tags: partition, lvm, resize2fs

I want to shrink my LVM physical volume and use this free space to create another partition for another OS.

I resized my root and home logical volumes using `lvresize` and now I'm trying to use `pvresize`, but I get the following error:

```
/dev/sda2: cannot resize to xxxxx extents as later ones are allocated.
```

This PV's free space is allocated between two logical volumes and I think that's the reason that  can't shrink the partition.

The output for `pvs -v --segments /dev/sda2` is:

```
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start SSize LV      Start Type   PE Ranges             
  /dev/sda2  volgroup0 lvm2 a--  446.64g 148.00g     0  7680 lv_root     0 linear /dev/sda2:0-7679      
  /dev/sda2  volgroup0 lvm2 a--  446.64g 148.00g  7680 51712 lv_home     0 linear /dev/sda2:7680-59391  
  /dev/sda2  volgroup0 lvm2 a--  446.64g 148.00g 59392 37888             0 free                         
  /dev/sda2  volgroup0 lvm2 a--  446.64g 148.00g 97280 17060 lv_root  7680 linear /dev/sda2:97280-114339
```

The free space is allocated between the segments 59392 and 97279. I know that `pmove` can move the free space to another segment, but I honestly don't know how to use it and I'm afraid of corrupting my data.

Could anyone please help me on this?
Thanks!

Comment: There is always a risk, in particular in case of power failure or so. When manipulating disk blocks, back up your data first. Suggestions without guarantee that it works: Perhaps a simple `pvmove /dev/sda2` does the job, or use the `--alloc anywhere` option as in the [examples section](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvmove.8.html#EXAMPLES) of the manual page.

Comment: @berndbausch tried this solution but it didn't worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pvmove moves segments, not free space.
You need to move this range
/dev/sda2:97280-114339
to start at segment 59392
Those are 17061 segments.

According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM#Shrinking) you should:

```
# pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/sda2:97280-114339 /dev/sda2:59392-76453
```

Then resize PV, then partition, and then enjoy your free space.
While LVM tries to avoid shooting yourself in the foot, this is a risky operation.
If you have any data that would cause you any trouble if it goes missing, **backup it first since you will most likely destroy it**.
Also, you can create a linux VM and test this commands until you feel confident in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that worked!
I'm not familiar with the concept of segments, do you know where I can learn more about this?

Comment: Under AlmaLinux 9, just running "pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/sda2" did the trick for me, effectively defragmenting my LVM allocation table.